# how big is too big for a swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I am making a flash game. And I want to know how big is too big for a swf file. Also, Ive been looking at my swf file and right now its at 38.2k. Is the swf file that gets created during debugging, is this the correct size for the file that will eventually be placed on the web.

thanks

Comment: This question is highly subjective depending on what you are building and who will be using it. However, if you feel it gets too big, start thinking about creating a preloader. (At 38k for a Flash game, however, I think that file is tiny.)

Comment: I would recommend creating a preloader regardless. And even a pre-preloader if your preloader itself is pretty hefty.

Comment: On my 56.6k modem it will take around 7 or 8 seconds to load your file and I find that unacceptable.

Comment: @Anon, what if the pre-preloader starts to put on some MB?

Comment: @dreamlax, you joke about it, but some of us are still stuck using carrier pigeons.

Comment: You could create a pre-pre-preloader, but by that point you need to start wondering whether your users are here for the game, or here for the preloaders.

Comment: And yes, some parts of the world are still on dial-up internet, and "7 or 8 seconds" needs a preloader.

Comment: If the preloader music's catchy, I'm hitting shift-F5 all day long. Poor pigeons.

Comment: @Tor Valamo, 
How is a comment like that is constructive or helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kilobytes is small stuff.

Anything less than a couple of megabytes is fine - once you get above that you might start worrying about loading times and keeping users interested during the preloader, but most portals accept files up to 10MB or so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the file is the same. A game of 38.2 kb is pretty small, if you go on Flash game sites they regularly run in the multiple of megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

The SWF is slightly smaller in release mode. The size difference is essentially nothing.

As for a guideline size, this depends on who you are expecting to play your game.

Answer (score 1):

if you want your game to reach a very wide audience keep it as small as you possibly can.
**a game without any heavy animation , embedded assets like png files or sound will usually be small**.
a good discussion regarding Optimal swf size for flash games here  at

> http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=788271

Answer (score 0):

The difference between debug and release builds is, according to my experience, some 30-40% in file size (debug version being bigger, of course), which is not insignificant.

Anyways, I think you're safe to assume that anything below 100kb is small enough to be considered an instant download, with no need to use preloaders. However, adding graphical and sound assets to the game will quickly push it up in size, at which point the preloader will probably be a good idea.